# Adding the Salesforce Certified Professional logo

Tags: certification

Are you permitted to add the Salesforce Certified Professional logo to your business card?

Comment: Why not, as long as you hold the certification! :)

Comment: I don't see how this Question "proposes ideas, solicits opinions, or provokes discussion."  It is a specific question with a single correct answer.  Although it is business-related rather than implementation-related, it seems inconsistent to allow questions about how to best prepare for cert exams (not implementation-related) but not questions like this one.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You sure are. The WebAssessor page you log in to (with the credentials provided in the "congratulations" email) to download the certification logo files states:

> The logo may be used on e-mail signatures, websites and **other printed materials**, as long as the certification logo is **not modified** in any way.

More details on the use of the logo can be found in the [Salesforce.com Certification Program Agreement](http://certification.salesforce.com/Salesforce.comCertificationProgramAgreement.pdf), which says:

> Upon successful completion of the Exam... SFDC grants You a personal, non-exclusive, non-transferable, revocable certification
>   designation (“Certification Designation”) and the right of use the applicable Certification Designation on
>   **business cards, resumes, and letterhead**. You may not use the Certification Designation in any way that: i)
>   may be construed to establish an affiliation between SFDC and any third parties other than You; or ii)
>   negatively impacts SFDC's reputation or goodwill. SFDC retains all rights, title and interests in the
>   Certification Designation. Nothing herein shall be construed to grant any other rights to You.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Guide to Certification link.](https://developer.salesforce.com/index.php?title=Certification&oldid=35267)

It States that you can use it on Business cards. Check point #2.

When you earn your credential by passing the requisite certification exam, you get:

1. A Salesforce.com Certified certificate
2. A Salesforce.com Certified logo to use on **business cards**, resumes,
   email signatures and social networking profiles
3. Free access to Release Training materials
4. Membership in the exclusive Salesforce Certified Professionals
   community
5. Personal growth and professional advancement

The link is last UPDATED July 2014. I will update this answer if I find any updated link